# How to control the flow of a CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, completable-future

Consider the following code:

```
final CompletableFuture<Object> future = giveMeFuture();

future.thenAcceptAsync(o -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("Some random exception happened.");
}).exceptionally(throwable -> {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION 1: " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
    return null;
});
future.exceptionally(throwable -> {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION 2: " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
    return null;
});
```

I notice the following behavior:

- When the future is completed normally, only `EXCEPTION 1` is printed. This is as expected, since we throw an exception in `thenAcceptAsync`.
- When the future is completed exceptionally, both `EXCEPTION 1` and `EXCEPTION 2` are printed.

I only want `EXCEPTION 1` to be printed when an exception happens in the execution of `thenAcceptAsync`. So in the second case, when the future is completed exceptionally, I only want `EXCEPTION 2` to be printed.

How can I do this with `CompletableFuture`? I know I could add a good old `try / catch` in `thenAcceptAsync`, but I am wondering if this could be done with solely `CompletableFuture` functionality.

**update**

The following flow will not work:

```
future
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION 2: " +throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    })
    .thenAcceptAsync(o -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Some random exception happened.");
    })
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION 1: " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    });
```

If we enter the `EXCEPTION 2` flow, we return `null`. Now `thenAcceptAsync` is called with a `null` argument. We could add a `null` check on parameter `o`, but this is not a good idea I think. We are waking up the executor thread to find out that the parameter `o` is `null`:

```
    .thenAcceptAsync(o -> {
        if (o != null) {
            // do something with the parameter
            throw new RuntimeException("Some random exception happened.");
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think the best way to approach this issue would be to use different exception types, and act accordingly in `exceptionally()`. This avoids the problem of converting exceptions into `null` (which might be a valid value for the non-exceptional flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    future
        .handleAsync((object, throwable) -> {
            if (throwable !=null) {
                    System.out.println("EXCEPTION from future completion: " + throwable.getClass().getName());
                return null;
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("async processing failed");
            }
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                System.out.println("EXCEPTION from completion stage: " + throwable.getClass().getName());
            return null;
        });
```

or changing your code to:

```
    future
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION 2: " +throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        })
        .thenAcceptAsync(o -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Some random exception happened.");
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION 1: " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        });
```

Every time you chain an operation to future, it executes separately from other "chaining". You were making two operation chains one with `future.thenAcceptAsync` and other with `future.exceptionally` and these execute separately from one another.

Comment: I added an update to my original post why the second flow will not work. I will try out your first solution now.

Comment: yes, the first one returns a `null` after handling the exception, so the `.thenAcceptAsync` will be called with `null`. It seems it's the first one that you need.

Comment: The first solution seems to work! It makes sense, as now we are handling the normal and exceptional case in the same block. The only downside is that I now am processing the exceptional case in the async executor. In my case, this is no problem, though it would be better if the exceptional case was run outside the async executor, in general, I think. Thank you @suenda!